What's the difference between 'createInitializePermanentDelegateInstruction' and 'approve'?
The createInitializePermanentDelegateInstruction sets a permanent delegate for a mint. But then why do I need to use the approve method?

The permanent delegate is mint-wide, so can be used to transfer tokens from any account belonging to the mint. It is controlled by the token mint creator.
"approve", on the other hand, only affects a single token account, and is controlled by the owner of the token account.
So the usage would be that the token mint creator can control the permanent delegate for all tokens, but a token user can approve a delegate on their account.
